# discord py - Why doesn't my ban command work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I would like to create a ban command with features such as embed answers, a log function and dm-ing the user when they're banned.

For some reason, my ban command does not run. Nothing happens when the command is executed and `if member is None` does not work for me either.

I have posted my code in the link provided:
**https://hastebin.com/ubayatiqey.py**

Why doesn't my bot answer my `=ban` command? Could I catch an error to fix it? Also, why don't Lines 41 to 48 not work as I expect them to?

Comment: `moved [my code to hastebin]` I don't get to see a thing. Highlights an advantage to including at least the pivotal part in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, that could possibly be because of the fact you don't have default values on the parameters. Also, I think you should start using command specific error handlings.

You can use `{command.name}.error` above a function to only handle errors from that specific command.

Below I added a few things and comments to show what could possibly be a fix to this issue.

```py
#The below code bans player.
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member = None, *, reason = None): # Adding "= None" to the end of parameters will tell the code that if someone who uses the command doesn't give a reason or a member, just set the values to None.
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send("⚠️ | Forgot Username")
    if reason is None:
        reason = "Adminban"
    else:
        reason = reason
 
    # Funktionen für Nachrichten
    embed = discord.Embed(title=" » Du wurdest ausgeschlossen!", description=f"Dein Account wurde so eben aus\nunserem Discord-Server ausgeschlossen.\n\n───────────────────────── \n ** | DETAILS ZU DEINER SPERRUNG..**\n Hier siehst du nun einige Details zu deiner Sperrung.\nDieses dienen sowohl als Info für dich, als auch für uns.\n\n┏‍♂️〢**Gesperrt von:** `{ctx.author}`\n┗〢**Grund:** `{reason}`\n\n───────────────────────── \n** » Du möchtest wieder auf unseren Server?**\nDann fülle dieses Formular aus:** https://bl4cklist.de/unban **", color=0xf04747)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.imgur.com/4np2bdK.png")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"BL4CKLIST.DEGAMING | Discord-Server", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/4np2bdK.png")
    embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/Ua2y6oF.png")
 
    response = choice([
    'https://media1.giphy.com/media/9jCTfM9QIzPLqAwkE9/giphy.gif',
    'https://media4.giphy.com/media/lY26OFBfrFFeecJEtT/giphy.gif',
    'https://media4.giphy.com/media/Q4Eu7AZO4FY14FMnTo/giphy.gif',
    'https://media3.giphy.com/media/BSdqZU7F0eRlXtAsPp/giphy.gif'
    ])
 
    embed1 = discord.Embed(title=f" » {member.name} wurde gesperrt!", description=f"Genaue Informationen zu der Sperrung:\n\n┏‍♂️〢**Ausgeschlossen von:** `{ctx.author}`\n┗〢**Grund der Sperrung:** `{reason}`", color=0xe74c3c)
    embed1.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed1.set_footer(text=f"BL4CKLIST.DEGAMING | Discord-Server", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/4np2bdK.png")
    embed1.set_image(url=f"{response}")
 
    embed2 = discord.Embed(title=" » Ein Mitglied wurde gesperrt!", description=f"Hier siehst du nun einige Details zur Sperrung.\n─────────────────────────\n\n» **Grund der Sperrung:** `{reason}`\n» **Name des Users:** `{member}`\n» **ID des Gesperrten:** `{member.id}`\n\n─────────────────────────", color=0xf04747)
    embed2.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed2.set_footer(text=f"BL4CKLIST.DEGAMING | Discord-Server", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/4np2bdK.png")
 
    channel = bot.get_channel(755014990465073306)
    # Funktionen für Nachrichten
 
    await member.send(embed=embed)
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
    await channel.send(embed=embed2)

# This part will track the errors specifically for the ban command only, and in this case, will print out the error 
@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    print (error)
```

Answer (score 0):

You had one mistake that prevented your entire code from being run. when you wrote `async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason):` that was a couple of lines off. First of all, you never defaulted member to be none, and you never defaulted reason to be none, so those both are still **required** arguments. If we rework the code we get
`async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member=None, *, reason=None):`.

Hope this helped! If you have any questions about this code or have unforseen errors, feel free to follow up!

Answer (score 0):

After going through your code I noticed a few things. Firstly, you were trying to print `error` which seems to be a variable which is never defined in your code. If you wanted to print an error whenever it is raised I would recommend that you make an error handler for the ban command. Secondly, you are trying to use `member` and `reason` as optional parameters, while they are never set as optional I would recommend changing that too. I also noticed that you were trying to use intents, I have no way of verifying weather you have intents enabled or not, but you need to enable them from the Discord Developers Portal. I would say you should try running the code without intents or enable them in the Discord Developers Portal. Let me know if this did not fix your issue.
If you want me to make all the changes, you can copy this code in paste it in your IDE.:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member=None, *, reason=None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send("⚠️ | Forgot Username")
        return
    if reason is None:
        reason = "Adminban"
    else:
        reason = reason
 
    # Funktionen für Nachrichten
    embed = discord.Embed(title=" » Du wurdest ausgeschlossen!", description=f"Dein Account wurde so eben aus\nunserem Discord-Server ausgeschlossen.\n\n───────────────────────── \n ** | DETAILS ZU DEINER SPERRUNG..**\n Hier siehst du nun einige Details zu deiner Sperrung.\nDieses dienen sowohl als Info für dich, als auch für uns.\n\n┏‍♂️〢**Gesperrt von:** `{ctx.author}`\n┗〢**Grund:** `{reason}`\n\n───────────────────────── \n** » Du möchtest wieder auf unseren Server?**\nDann fülle dieses Formular aus:** https://bl4cklist.de/unban **", color=0xf04747)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://i.imgur.com/4np2bdK.png")
    embed.set_footer(text=f"BL4CKLIST.DEGAMING | Discord-Server", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/4np2bdK.png")
    embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/Ua2y6oF.png")
 
    response = choice([
    'https://media1.giphy.com/media/9jCTfM9QIzPLqAwkE9/giphy.gif',
    'https://media4.giphy.com/media/lY26OFBfrFFeecJEtT/giphy.gif',
    'https://media4.giphy.com/media/Q4Eu7AZO4FY14FMnTo/giphy.gif',
    'https://media3.giphy.com/media/BSdqZU7F0eRlXtAsPp/giphy.gif'
    ])
 
    embed1 = discord.Embed(title=f" » {member.name} wurde gesperrt!", description=f"Genaue Informationen zu der Sperrung:\n\n┏‍♂️〢**Ausgeschlossen von:** `{ctx.author}`\n┗〢**Grund der Sperrung:** `{reason}`", color=0xe74c3c)
    embed1.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed1.set_footer(text=f"BL4CKLIST.DEGAMING | Discord-Server", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/4np2bdK.png")
    embed1.set_image(url=f"{response}")
 
    embed2 = discord.Embed(title=" » Ein Mitglied wurde gesperrt!", description=f"Hier siehst du nun einige Details zur Sperrung.\n─────────────────────────\n\n» **Grund der Sperrung:** `{reason}`\n» **Name des Users:** `{member}`\n» **ID des Gesperrten:** `{member.id}`\n\n─────────────────────────", color=0xf04747)
    embed2.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed2.set_footer(text=f"BL4CKLIST.DEGAMING | Discord-Server", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/4np2bdK.png")
 
    channel = bot.get_channel(755014990465073306)
    # Funktionen für Nachrichten
 
    await member.send(embed=embed)
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
    await channel.send(embed=embed2)


# Error handler
@ban.error()
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error):
        print(error)
```